# Are Poisson Regressions with Serial Correlation Biased or Inconsistent? (No Fixed Effects)

Tags: autocorrelation, bias, poisson-regression, consistency, clustered-standard-errors

Let's say I've got panel data where a count outcome $y$ and continuous independent variable $x$ observed each time period $t=(1,2,...T)$ for each individual $i$. I am interested in how $x_{it}$ affects all future values of $y$.

So let $\overline{y}_{it} = \sum^T_{\tau=t} y_{i\tau} $, then I estimate a standard looking Poisson model as:

$\mathbb{E}[\overline{y}_{it} | \alpha , \beta] = exp(\alpha + x_{it}\beta)$

Clearly there will be serial correlation in the error terms within individuals ("errors" given by: $\overline{y}_{it} - exp(\alpha + x_{it}\beta)$) because each outcome includes future outcomes.

Is an unbiased estimated of $\beta$ obtainable by estimating a Poisson model with cluster robust standard errors? i.e. by something like this in STATA:

"poisson ybar x, vce(cluster i)"

if ybar=$\overline{y}$

Comment: I would check Cameron & Trivedi; I believe under what they call the 'LEF' (conditional expected $y$ is $\exp(x^{\top}\beta)$) is all that is required for consistency. I believe the serial correlation may lead to bad inference, however.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. And by "inference" do you mean the standard errors being incorrect? Wouldn't the clustering at the I level account for this?

Comment: yes, 'inference'=standard errors on coefficients (or the divergence of the model as a whole).

Comment: Some alternatives for count data with possible serial correlation: Brandt's 'pewma', cf [here](http://www.utdallas.edu/~pxb054000/code/count-examples/ECTS-I-2010.pdf) and [code](http://www.utdallas.edu/~pbrandt/code/pests.r).